# Generalisation of $ \sum \frac {1}{k}-\ln n=\gamma$ to $0 \lt\alpha \lt1 , \sum \frac{1}{k^\alpha}-f(n)= \beta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, divergent-series

looking at [Find the value of : $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left({2\sqrt n}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79115/find-the-value-of-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left2-sqrt-n-sum-limit)

and knowing that for 
$$\alpha=1 ,\lim_{ n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k^\alpha}-\ln n=\gamma$$

Makes one wonder if there are other results for 
 $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1 $

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k^\alpha}-f(n)=\beta$$

where $f,\beta$ are determined by the value of $\alpha$

is there a topic that relates to some results similar to above?

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^\alpha} - f(n) = \beta$?

Comment: Have you heard of Riemann-Stieltjes integration?

Comment: Also, do you mean $\alpha\geq -1$?

Comment: @r9m : yes, I better use that format instead

Comment: @Clayton : cleaned up to clarify, thank you.

Comment: @Clayton : yes to Riemann integration, but if that was enough why $\gamma$ is such a big deal? then all the cases I am looking at can be done as lower/bound of  integral. which makes asking this question extremely stupid as that is what I am feeling now :( .
I think that is my answer, forgot the basics.

Comment: Mathematica gives that when $f(x) = \int \frac{1}{x^a} dx = \frac{x^{-a+1}}{-a+1}$ then $\beta = \zeta(a)$.

Comment: @VVejalla : so according to that for $\alpha = 1$ we have $\beta = \gamma = \zeta(1)$ ?

Comment: Only for $\alpha > 0, \alpha \not = 1$, it seems to be true.

Comment: @VVejalla One of the definition of $\ln x$ uses that with $\lim \alpha \to 1$

Comment: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2110434), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/977205), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609704), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3963153)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\Re \alpha>1$. In terms of the Hurwitz zeta function (http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11)
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^\alpha }}}  = \zeta (\alpha) - \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^\alpha }}}  = \zeta (\alpha) + \frac{1}{{n^\alpha }} - \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^\alpha }}}  = \zeta (\alpha) + \frac{1}{{n^\alpha }} - \zeta (\alpha,n),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\zeta (\alpha) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^\alpha }}}  - \frac{1}{{n^\alpha }} + \zeta (\alpha,n).
$$
By analytic continuation, this formula is valid for all complex $\alpha\neq 1$. Now you can use, for example, http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E28 to obtain a more explicit expression that is valid in half-planes of the form $\Re \alpha>-(2N+1)$. You can also use the asymptotic expansion
$$
\zeta (\alpha,n) \sim \frac{{n^{1 - \alpha} }}{{\alpha - 1}} + \frac{1}{{2n^\alpha }} + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}\frac{{\Gamma (\alpha + 2m - 1)}}{{\Gamma (\alpha)}}\frac{1}{{n^{\alpha + 2n - 1} }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ with fixed $\alpha \neq 1$ (http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E43). Here $B_m$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers. In particular,
$$
\zeta (\alpha) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^\alpha }}}  + \frac{{n^{1 - \alpha} }}{{\alpha - 1}} - \frac{1}{{2n^\alpha }} + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {\frac{{B_{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}\frac{{\Gamma (\alpha + 2m - 1)}}{{\Gamma (\alpha)}}\frac{1}{{n^{\alpha + 2n - 1} }}} } \right)
$$
for all $\alpha\neq 1$ and $N$ satisfying $\Re \alpha >  - (2N + 1)$. Therefore, with your notation, $\beta =\zeta(\alpha)$ and
$$
f(n)= -\frac{{n^{1 - \alpha} }}{{\alpha - 1}} + \frac{1}{{2n^\alpha }} - \sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {\frac{{B_{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}\frac{{\Gamma (\alpha + 2m - 1)}}{{\Gamma (\alpha)}}\frac{1}{{n^{\alpha + 2n - 1} }}}
$$
with $N = \left\lceil { - \frac{{\Re \alpha  + 1}}{2}} \right\rceil$, $\alpha\neq 1$ and with empty sums being interpreted as $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
$$\zeta(\alpha)=\frac 1 {\alpha-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{ \gamma _n}{n!} \,(\alpha-1)^n$$ which is very accurate (just try summing from $0$ to $4$).

Comment: I do not think this answers the question.